# Receive push notification in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a NodeJS application that should receive notifications from FCM. I've seen in the FCM documentation that you can send, but not receive notifications in the current version.

I've already searched alternatives for FCM, like pushy but seems that they have the same problem, only send notifications, not receive.

Currently I'm poling a REST api every 30 seconds to check for changes but obviously this is not the perfect scenario.

Is there any opensource or commercial solution that can receive notifications from a service, similar to firebase?

Comment: Is FCM = Firebase Cloud Messaging?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Kin Yes by FCM I'm refering to Firebase. According to the documentation it's possible to send messages to clients iOS, Android, or web (JavaScript) client app. What I need is to have a node.js app as client.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty The problem is that according to the documentation node.js is not a supported client (only iOS, Android and web javascript) and I need a node.js app to receive messages

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not really. I don't think it's possible atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find
https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/push-receiver for node
and https://github.com/Francesco149/push_receiver for python